# How to setup environment to build, compile, debug BCBIO Variation

Tags: java, clojure, ide

Link to GIT src : https://github.com/chapmanb/bcbio.variation

I would like to use an IDE like eclipse, IntelliJ or Netbeans.
The code uses clojure and java.

Comment: The page actually mentions leiningen explicitly. What did you try already?

Comment: I was able to set up build environment using Leiningen and IntelliJ. But this just gives me the capability to compile and build. I want the capability to step through the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [Cursive](https://cursiveclojure.com/) plugin for IntelliJ is an extremely popular IDE for Clojure. It has most of or all the features you'd expect in a modern IDE (keep in mind that it's relatively new). Emacs with Cider is also very popular and is the defacto standard for clojure development.

The second tool you need to be aware of is [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) Which if the universally accepted build and project tool for Clojure. It is used by Cursive and all the other popular tools.

Happy Hacking!

Comment: I tried Cursive, but I need  Leiningen to build the application to a jar file before running it. So i cannot step through the code. I can only edit and build jar to execute. I cannot execute directly from the IDE